# Application crashed after an hour in android while resuming

Tags: android

My android application crashed, when i sent that to background for half an hour and then launched from home.

the logcat information is goes below.

```
06-20 13:13:39.839: E/AndroidRuntime(23778):    ... 20 more
06-20 13:13:39.839: E/AndroidRuntime(23778): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 13:13:39.839: E/AndroidRuntime(23778):    at com.globalnest.CaptureActivity.onCreate(CaptureActivity.java:116)
06-20 13:13:39.839: E/AndroidRuntime(23778):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-20 13:13:39.839: E/AndroidRuntime(23778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
06-20 13:13:39.839: E/AndroidRuntime(23778):    ... 27 more
06-20 13:13:39.849: W/ActivityManager(255):   Force finishing activity com.globalnest/.AdminTabHost
06-20 13:13:39.869: D/dalvikvm(23778): GC_CONCURRENT freed 204K, 48% free 2898K/5511K, external 1040K/1552K, paused 3ms+14ms
06-20 13:13:40.359: W/ActivityManager(255): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{2b62c908 com.globalnest/.AdminTabHost}
06-20 13:13:45.409: D/lights(255): set_light_buttons: brightness=0
06-20 13:13:46.239: D/dalvikvm(22012): GC_CONCURRENT freed 465K, 49% free 3008K/5895K, external 743K/1036K, paused 9ms+2ms
06-20 13:13:49.409: W/ActivityManager(255): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
06-20 13:13:49.669: W/ActivityManager(255): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{2b62c908 com.globalnest/.AdminTabHost}
06-20 13:13:50.389: W/ActivityManager(255): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{2b59f888 com.globalnest/.Main}
06-20 13:13:55.469: D/dalvikvm(22012): GC_EXPLICIT freed 138K, 52% free 2869K/5895K, external 743K/1036K, paused 80ms
06-20 13:13:59.679: W/ActivityManager(255): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{2b62c908 com.globalnest/.AdminTabHost}
06-20 13:14:00.139: D/dalvikvm(671): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 49% free 2782K/5379K, external 1404K/1557K, paused 85ms
06-20 13:14:00.199: D/dalvikvm(671): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3K, 49% free 2783K/5379K, external 1404K/1557K, paused 25ms
06-20 13:14:00.199: W/CursorWrapperInner(671): Cursor finalized without prior close()
06-20 13:14:02.419: D/lights(255): set_light_backlight: brightness=20
06-20 13:14:09.419: D/lights(255): set_light_backlight: brightness=0
06-20 13:14:09.419: I/power(255): *** set_screen_state 0
06-20 13:14:09.419: D/DASH - select(255): sensors_select_callback: select canceled by request
06-20 13:14:09.419: D/DASH - select(255): sensors_select_callback: select canceled by request
06-20 13:14:09.429: D/kernel(126): [50267.656494] request_suspend_state: sleep (0->3) at 50264074243382 (2012-06-20 07:44:09.423339839 UTC)
06-20 13:14:09.429: D/kernel(126): [50267.656616] as3676 0-0040: as3676_early_suspend
06-20 13:14:09.429: D/kernel(126): [50267.659759] cyttsp-spi spi0.0: cyttsp_suspend: Enter
06-20 13:14:09.449: D/SurfaceFlinger(255): About to give-up screen, flinger = 0x91bf8
06-20 13:14:09.919: D/kernel(126): [50268.142242] active wake lock PowerManagerService
06-20 13:14:09.919: D/kernel(126): [50268.142272] active wake lock bq24185_watchdog_lock
06-20 13:14:09.919: D/kernel(126): [50268.142272] active wake lock usb_bus_active
06-20 13:14:09.919: D/kernel(126): [50268.142272] active wake lock msm_otg
06-20 13:14:09.919: D/kernel(126): [50268.142303] wake lock msm_serial_hs_rx, expired
06-20 13:14:09.919: D/kernel(126): [50268.142303] wake lock wifi_rx_wake, expired
06-20 13:14:09.939: W/ActivityManager(255): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{2b59f888 com.globalnest/.Main}
06-20 13:14:14.489: I/ActivityManager(255): Start proc com.sonyericsson.lockscreen.notifications for broadcast com.sonyericsson.lockscreen.notifications.facebook/.LockscreenReceiver: pid=23791 uid=10058 gids={3003}
06-20 13:14:14.579: I/ActivityThread(23791): Pub com.sonyericsson.lockscreen.notifications: com.sonyericsson.lockscreen.notifications.provider.NotificationProvider
06-20 13:14:14.759: D/dalvikvm(255): GC_CONCURRENT freed 499K, 39% free 8315K/13447K, external 2950K/3252K, paused 3ms+8ms
06-20 13:14:15.679: I/ActivityManager(255): Process com.sonyericsson.android.datamonitor (pid 22012) has died.
06-20 13:14:15.689: W/kernel(126): [50273.912445] select 21040 (com.aricent.mtp), adj 10, size 3198, to kill
06-20 13:14:15.689: W/kernel(126): [50273.912506] select 22012 (oid.datamonitor), adj 10, size 3567, to kill
```

please any one help me...

THnaking you.

Comment: CaptureActivity.java see line no 116 something is null

Answer (score 1):

```
06-20 13:13:39.839: E/AndroidRuntime(23778): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 13:13:39.839: E/AndroidRuntime(23778):    at com.globalnest.CaptureActivity.onCreate(CaptureActivity.java:116)
```

There's your clue. Look at line 116 of CaptureActivity.java and figure out what could be unexpectedly `null`.

Comment: No, it is the answer to the question. Something on line 116 is null. That is what's causing the crash. It's not a comment, it's an answer.

Comment: actually line no 116 is commented and if me could not live the application more than half an hour it is working fine.

Comment: it is working fine all the time if me could not pause this activity

Comment: Well, just because Line 116 is commented, doesn't mean that's not the problem at all. Could it be something around (Before or after) that?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably assume that your process was killed by the Android OS if it was in the background for half an hour. So when you start the application again, the Android OS will recreate the process and restart **only the Activity that was on top of the stack**.

If the Activity at the top of the stack relies on anything else (that other activities may have set up before), then your app will crash. This is because the entire activity stack is **not recreated**.

With that in mind, review what might happen in that case.